# Web3's eth_sign with metamask notification never closes and promise doesn't resolve!

Tags: web3js, metamask

I'm trying to call web3's eth_sign with metamask's provider, like so

```js
        var signature = await web3.eth.sign(web3.utils.utf8ToHex(randomMsg),acc0)
```

The metamask windows notification pops up and everything works correctly, I click on Sign and it seems to work since the loading finishes and I'm returned to the list of transactions, **but the notification never closes and the eth_sign promise never resolves**.

I'm using web3.js version 1.2.4 and the latest metamask. I've tried updating to the 2.0.0 alpha version of Web3 but the same happened.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up using the `web3.eth.personal.sign` function instead. I thought I needed to add a password but it turns out if I don't add a password to the function parameters, it will use metamask to sign.

Answer (score 1):

You must to encrypt your message by `web3.utils.sha3` instead of `web3.utils.utf8ToHex`.