# metamask eth_sign can't make it work

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, metamask, ethereumjs

I have this:

```
ethereum.request({ 
        method: 'eth_sign', 
        params: 
            {
                from: account, //this is the address
                message: '0xfafa'
            }
        
    }).then(data => {
        console.log("data ", data);
    })
```

> Seems like the error states:  RPC Error: Invalid parameters: must
> provide an Ethereum address.

What's the right syntax to make it work ?

Comment: From https://eth.wiki/json-rpc/API#eth_sign it appears `params` should be an array. In any case you can inject any web3 version in your project, you shouldn't depend on Metamask copy.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have to enable account:

```
    var accounts = await ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' })
```

after that, you can use Metamask enabled accounts

Comment: now you can't .

Comment: https://github.com/alexeyneu/onboard/blob/0e8286e1b6b62077790b0530dc11328d7e26bf92/src/Onboard/BoardForm.jsx#L21-L23     fails

Answer (score 1):

`web3` is no longer available from MetaMask and you have to use the `ethereum` object to call `personal_sign`:

```js
const message = "Hello from Ethereum Stack Exchange!";
const accounts = await ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' });
const account = accounts[0];
const signature = await ethereum.request({ method: 'personal_sign', params: [ message, account ] });
```

Note, that you have to connect to MetaMask first by calling `eth_requestAccounts`. We use the first best available account to sign the message.

Also, don't use `eth_sign`, use `personal_sign`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try using `web3.eth.personal.sign(message, account)`

-> Returns a promise
[reference post](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/54723/68019)

Usually this requires a third parameter password but [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/84612/68019) someone says without providing a pass it uses MetaMask to sign.

Comment: We cant use web3 anymore directly since metamask does not allow it ...

Comment: Hmmm... that's tricky because on their docs they linked an example project on GitHub where they use web3? -> https://github.com/danfinlay/js-eth-personal-sign-examples/blob/master/index.js

Comment: True ! Their docs sometimes is outdated

Comment: Their docs are still outdated. Anyone have a clue on what to do without `web3` on hand?

Comment: @DaveStein nifty wallet. not the best one for sure but works at least. in four cases out of 5 it's recognized by dapps as metamask